# Using Navigation properties?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I'm trying to set a foreign key with

```
protected void AdresDetailsView_ItemInserting(object sender,     DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    var Id = Convert.ToInt32(CustomerDropDownList.SelectedValue);
    e.Values["Customer_Id"] = Id;
}
```

This does not work because my entity (Adres) does not have a property Customer_Id.
Customer_Id is the column name in the database and I should use the Customer property which is the navigation property.
But I don't know how to.

I'm using EF 4.5

Comment: You should, somewhere in your application, have the code that was generated by Entity Framework for your domain classes. Even if you didn't use code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to modify your navigation properties to use foreign key properties. This would let your class have both a `Customer` and a `CustomerId`/`Customer_Id`/whatever you want property, that are kept synchronized. You can then update the customer ID the way you're trying to now. However, you don't specify which version of EF you are using, and older versions do not support foreign key properties.

If foreign key properties are not an option, you need to make sure the customer with ID `Id` exists in your context. This will be something like `var customer = context.Customers.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == Id);` You can then set the `Customer` property to that specific customer.

Comment: ohh sorry, Im using EF 4.5, included this in my question now

Comment: If I try to use your code I get "The name 'context' does not exist in the current context" as a compiller error

Comment: @MichielT "something like" :) You'd need to use the context you're already creating. I don't know how you've named it. Or perhaps you're using something that creates it for you behind the scenes. That aside, with .NET 4.5's EF, you should be able to use foreign keys, so you don't need to take the complicated route.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, I was aware that I could set foreign key properties, just thought I did not have to because I had navigation properties for that. But if creating those foreign key properties is that much easier ill go with that.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Code First?  If so, I would recommend creating your own foreign key properties and using the [Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664363%28v=PandP.50%29.aspx) to establish your constraints and relationships.